# Показать форму заполнения после отправки сообщения

Tags: jquery, ajax, css, javascript

```
$('document').ready(function(){
                $('#form').validate(
                {   
                    // правила для проверки
                    rules:{
                        name: {
                            required: true,
                            minlength: 2,
                            maxlength: 30
                            },                      
                        phone: {
                            required: true,
                            number: true,
                            minlength: 5,
                            maxlength: 15
                            }

                    },

                    // выводимые сообщения при нарушении соответствующих правил
                    messages:{
                        "name":{
                            required: "Заполните это поле",
                                    minlength: "От 2 до 30 символов",
                                    maxlength: "От 2 до 30 символов"
                        },

                        "phone":{
                            required: "Заполните это поле",
                            number: "Только цифры",
                            minlength: "От 5 до 15 символов",
                            maxlength: "От 5 до 15 символов"
                        }

                    },

                    // указаваем обработчик
                    submitHandler: function(form){
                        $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                            target: '#preview', 
                            success: function() { 
                                $('#contact_form').slideUp("fast", function(){
                                $(this).before("<div id='checkmark'><img src='img/check.png'><p>Спасибо за заявку! В ближайшее время мы свяжемся с Вами !</p></div>");

                            }) 
                            } 
                        }); 
                    }

                })
            });
```

Так вот вопрос: как сделать чтобы после отправки сообщения - окно с сообщением исчезло и появилась снова форма для заполнения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

просто верните окно сообщения (тут 3 секунды) и удалите сообщение

```
success: function() { 
                                $('#contact_form').slideUp("fast", function(){
                                $(this).before("<div id='checkmark'><img src='img/check.png'><p>Спасибо за заявку! В ближайшее время мы свяжемся с Вами !</p></div>");

                            }).delay(3000).slideDown('fast',function() {$(this).prev().remove();});
                            }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/ZHQRk/

Comment: Спасибо! Я так понимаю вместо slideDown можно использовать любой другой эффект?

Comment: ну тут важно понимать, что delay работает только с анимацией, если хотите просто показать то надо все равно указывать время, например show(0);

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/ZHQRk/ этот пример работает - а вот этот
success: function() { 
                                $('#contact_form').slideUp("fast", function(){
                                $(this).before("<div id='checkmark'><img src='img/check.png'><p>Спасибо за заявку! В ближайшее время мы свяжемся с Вами !</p></div>");

                            }).delay(3000).slideDown('fast',function() {$(this).prev().remove();});
                            } почему не работает наверное delay добавить необходимо

Comment: [всё работает](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/ZHQRk/1/) посмотрите в консоль, может со скобками накосячили.